# Is my proof of the limit of a product of functions correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Given that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=F$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=G$, prove that $lim_{x \to a}f(x)g(x) = FG$.

Rewriting the givens in delta-epsilon notation, we have: $\forall \epsilon_f>0, \exists \delta_f>0: 0<|x-a|<\delta_f \implies |f(x)-F|<\epsilon_f$

$\forall \epsilon_g>0, \exists \delta_g>0: 0<|x-a|<\delta_g \implies |f(x)-F|<\epsilon_g$

Proceed by constructing a delta-epsilon statement about the product $f(x)g(x)$. Some scratch work:

$|f(x)-F||g(x)-G| < \epsilon_f\epsilon_g$

$|f(x)g(x) - Gf(x) - Fg(x) + FG| < \epsilon_f\epsilon_g$

$|f(x)g(x) - (Gf(x) - FG) - (Fg(x) - FG) - FG| < \epsilon_f\epsilon_g$

$|f(x)g(x) - FG| - |(Gf(x) - FG) + (Fg(x) - FG)|< \epsilon_f\epsilon_g$

$|f(x)g(x) - FG| < \epsilon_f\epsilon_g +|(Gf(x) - FG) + (Fg(x) - FG)|$

Since this is a strict inequality, we can assert the existence of some $\epsilon$ that is in between the LHS and RHS:

$|f(x)g(x) - FG| < \epsilon < \epsilon_f\epsilon_g + |(Gf(x) - FG) + (Fg(x) - FG)|$

We then chain together the two deltas by taking the minimum: $\delta = min(\delta_f, \delta_g)$.

Therefore we can state the existence of the limit of $f(x)g(x)$, carrying along some baggage:

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0: 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)g(x) - FG| < \epsilon < \epsilon_f\epsilon_g + |(Gf(x) - FG) + (Fg(x) - FG)|$

Comment: This is not quite right, as explained by bc78. Hint: $|f(x)g(x)-FG|=|f(x)g(x)-f(x)G+f(x)G -FG|$.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your solution is not correct. To achieve your conclusion, it must be correct for any chosen $\epsilon$. However, in your solution, you use a specific $\epsilon$ which is between LHS and RHS.

Comment: It's more important that $\epsilon$ can be an arbitrarily small number than arbitrarily large.